# Formal Hebrew honorific for one's mother

Tags: names, torah-service, women, hebrew, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Many men, when going up for an aliya, tell the gabbai their name as, e.g. "Reuven ben **Rav** Yaakov", even if "Yaakov," the father, isn't actually a Rabbi." I believe the reason for this practice is to honor the father by not saying his name without an honorific.

Is there an honorific that's used commonly when referring to one's mother? For example, if Reuven was to ask the gabbai to mention his brother in a ["Mi Shebeirach"](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/texts/Liturgy_and_Prayers/Siddur_Prayer_Book/Torah_Service/Prayer_for_the_Sick.shtml), in which one traditionally identifies the patient with his/her mother, how should he say the name? "Shim'on ben **Giveret** Leah"? "... **Imi (my mother)** Leah"?

Happy Mothers' Day!

Comment: I've seen the custom to use the honorific "Reb", which is used for a non-rabbi, but using the title "Rav" where that person doesn't have Semicha seems problematic to me. Having said that,  I have come accross this practice in Charedi yeshivot, where not having semicha is the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: @Meir I have often heard Chassidim add even more; "Moreinu HaRav" for regular people!

Comment: @Meir See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18644/why-call-so-many-olim-moreinu?rq=1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Ha-isha" (האשה) is a title of respect that has the advantage of sounding perfectly natural.

Comment: My Rav would use that title.

Comment: Agreed. I'd translate it as "The Lady"

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how honorifics work with regards to *Mi SheBerachs*, but my impression is that the traditional honorific for a woman is *marat*.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, "giveret" is a modern Hebrew transposition (some would say mutilation) of "gever."

Comment: On both my great-grandmother's headstone and her memorial plaque in the shul, her name is preceeded with "marat".  She passed away in 1940 and the headstone and plaque are from that era.  One more comment, her headstone also contains the word "ha-isha" before her name.