# mi shebeirach for yourself when calling a relative up for an aliyah

Tags: halacha, torah-service, family-members, kavod, gabbai

I have been looking at the halachot for a son who is the gabbai and who calls his father up for an aliyah [here](https://www.chazaq.org/?section=articles&categoryId=52&articleId=395) and I know that there was a [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-does-a-son-call-up-his-father-for-an-aliyah) about it, but my question is about after the aliyah. When making the מי שבירך afterwards, one often includes the name of relatives. How does the gabbai refer to himself if the father wishes to give a bracha to his children? The gabbai adds in something like "avi umori" out of respect, so he probably doesn't need to add "achi" if his brother and family get the מי שבירך but does he refer to himself and his children in the third person?

Comment: I have seen gabbais mentioniong themselves on occasion, and in my experience, usually they just say "oti, vishti, etc."

Comment: Like @Daniel, I've generally heard "_v'osi_" (except by one _gabay_ whose command of Hebrew was, apparently poor, who said "_v'es osi_").

Answer (score 2):

I've seen the Gabbai Sheni say it instead, to avoid the distasteful move of calling out "God bless me!"

Answer (score 1):

I have been a gabbai and my sons are gabbaim. My sons refer to their brothers as 'Ploni ben Avi Mori' and their sons as 'Bni Ploni' without using their own names. I think that they would also refer to their wives as 'Ishti Plonis bas Ploni' and that is often how I would do it when I was gabbai.

Note that we would first check with the rav of the shul to make sure what the minhag was before doing this. This was not just something that we came up with on our own.

Comment: Are you or your sons respected halachik authorities that we should care what you have chosen to do? Were your decisions based on some other authority that you can cite? After all, we don't know you.

Comment: @DoubleAA I was giving the minhag as my LOR and the rabbonim at the shuls that my sons are gabbaim have explained to us what to do. This includes the bais medrash at YU where one of my sons served as gabbai when he was there (before he got semicha).

Answer (score 1):

My son is gabbai and asked our Rav what to do.

He calls me up and refers to me in the brocho afterwards as אבי מורי הכהן. In the brocho afterwards he refers to all other family members as he would for anyone else, i.e. אשתו, בניו, בנותיו etc and not אמי, אחי, אחיותי