# process for Gabbai to call his son to the Torah

Tags: torah-service, gabbai

If the father is the Gabbai ,how should he call his son up for an Aliyah ? Does the father use his own name for example Yaakov ben Moshe? or Yaakov Bnee?

Comment: Hey martin, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thank you for your interesting question (+1).....you might want to consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-does-a-son-call-up-his-father-for-an-aliyah

Comment: A gabbai in a shteibel used to regular call his firstborn son, and mention always "Bni bechori Nadav".  Data point, but hardly an answer really.

Answer (score 5):

I have been a gabbai and the way I was trained was יעמוד בני יוסף without mentioning my own name. That is also the way that I have seen other gabbaim do it.

When my sons who are gabbaim mention their children in a mi shebeirach (as an example) they also say 'Bni Ploni' or 'Biti Ploni' without using ben or bas and their names. When they call up their brother, they say 'Ploni ben Avi Mori'. When they call me or reference me or my wife it is 'Avi Mori' or 'Imi Morasi'

**UPDATE** For Yizkor, the nusach in various siddurim and machzorim is Avi Mori Ploni ben Ploni. I have not seen a write up discussing the difference. You can also see a link in the comments to that nusach when calling up also. My answer was based on how I was taught and how my sons were taught in their Yeshivos.

Comment: I've heard that for calling up a father, there is a heter for using his name.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Whether there is or not, this is the way we have done it. If you follow the link to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-does-a-son-call-up-his-father-for-an-aliyah you will see in the answer that one could use the name if the honorific is used. However, our minhag is to be makpid not to use the name.

Comment: Did someone of notable authority train you to do this?

Comment: @DoubleAA At YU originally. My sons have gone to both YU and Ner Yisroel as well as Yeshiva in Eretz Yisroel.

Answer (score 1):

What I've always seen done was יעמוד בני יוסף בן שמעון where the Gabbai is Shimon.

Comment: I've seen that too, but why? What's wrong with just "יוסף בן שמעון"?

Comment: @IsaacMoses because it implies that it is a different שמעון When calling children or parents the relation should be said (at least that is the way I have been taught)