# How would a Gabbai call up his firstborn son, who is a Rabbi, for an Aliyah

Tags: names, torah-service, family-members, honors

Torah Service, Gabbai duties, Hebrew names and titles, honors due relatives

Comment: Yaamod HaRav.....

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14591/27180 & https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46177/27180

Comment: Probably "yaamod beni bechori Harav ploni", or whichever way a gabbai would generally call up his son, but with bechori added after beni (if he says beni), and with Harav before the name.