# Calling an Esteemed Rabbi for Aliyah by His Title and Not His Name

Tags: halacha

As can be seen [in this vide](https://youtu.be/kDzxxMAVCls?si=lQ5GLF5kZ3t56aNT&t=60) The Rebbe was called up for Aliyah (as well as for Hakafos) by his title "Admu"r ben Harav Levi Yitzchok" and not by his name "Menachem Mendel ben Levi Yitzchok".

Is there a precedent for this, and is it done by other rabbis?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-does-a-son-call-up-his-father-for-an-aliyah