# Why call so many olim "moreinu"?

Tags: words, torah-service, chasidut-hasidism, derech-eretz-manners

I davened in a couple of different Chassidish shuls over the past few days, and in two different places (Tenka and Munkacs), I noticed that nearly all men who were called up for an aliya were addressed as what sounded like "moreinu" (or, in context "muraynee") and possibly even "moreinu harav," if I heard right. This included people who were definitely not the Rabbi of that shul.

- Is it likely that I heard right?
- If so, what is the meaning and basis of this practice? Why call everyone "our teacher"?

Comment: Do you know if the people called up had smichah, even if they weren't rabbi of that shul?

Comment: @ba, No, I don't. Unfortunately, I didn't take more detailed note of who got this title and who didn't.

Comment: I have heard of shuls who, in order not to embarrass anyone, call up everyone as "rav". Could this be a similar practice -- giving all kavod so as not to exclude anyone?

Comment: @Dan, I know some places call people up as HaChaver. My only issue with this, is that you then get people taking that title with them, like this past Shabbath, when someone visiting was given an 'Aliyah at my Shul, and he told the Gabbi his name was [Ploni] ben HaChaver Rav [Almoni].

Comment: @SethJ I know someone on whom the title HaChaver was conferred.  Are you saying it's a problem when it's HaCh"R **Rav**?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, I mean that (generally) this is not a formal title given to individuals. It is often given as a way of not making anyone feel bad. In some Shuls, I've been told, everyone gets called up as "Reb [Ploni]", so the title "HaChaver" was given to _actual_ rabbis (other than the officiating rabbi of the Shul, is usually "Moreinu" or "HaRav"). But then the "Chaver"im (it seems) have taken that title with them elsewhere, so that their children insist on being called up as I described. I kind of see it, LeHavdil, like hyphenated last names. At a certain point you have to stop adding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In certain Chasidish circles, you are *knighted* with the title *Moreinu* after being tested on a certain (large) number of Daf. This is often done as a "graduation ceremeny" with certificates handed out. the frum news sites sometimes report about such events.

See [this link](http://www.kayj.net/he/forum/minhogim/92-the-title-chaver) for a small discussion about the Moreinu title in days begone. The best response seems to be:

> Originally, **Chover** was a title given to someone who learned in Yeshivah for a few years and was able to continue learning by himself. **Moreinu** was a title given to someone who is able to be מורה הוראה and to pasken in halochic questions.
>   Today these titles are given differently.