# Addressing mother as teacher

Tags: chinuch-education, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, rebbe-talmid-muvhak

Children are not supposed to call their parents by their first name because it implies a casual rather than respectful relationship.

My daughter attends the school where my wife is a teacher. The teachers each have their preference for how students should address them, and my wife is *Morah* Kareen (her first name).

When a child is in her mother's class, is it appropriate for her to refer to her mother as "Morah ____," like the other children, or must she avoid saying her mother's name altogether, even with a title?

Comment: Regarding what your daughter should do, I encourage you to [ask your rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi). Mi Yodeya [can't make](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi) a halachic ruling for you. For this issue in particular, I strongly suspect that communal and familial norms would be important inputs into the ruling/guidance of a rabbi who knows your community and family or at least can discuss them in depth with you.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7112/formal-hebrew-honorific-for-ones-mother

Comment: As a practical matter: I know and have known a number of people who were their respective parents' students in school. It can be awkward for the student (not knowing what to call the parent), but what I understand usually works best, for older grades anyway, is whatever the child calls the parent at home.

Comment: To work around the issue, your wife can be *mochel* on her honor and allow your daughter to call her by her first name.

Comment: Why can't she just call her *Morah* without the name? And, so that she doesn't have a different standard than the rest of the class, apply the same rule to everyone?

Comment: Morah is a respectful title, even with a first name. It would be more similar to calling a father "Rabbi Yaakov" than calling said father "Mr. Yaakov".

Comment: @LN6595 I know of no one who refers to a rav in a superior position (student-teacher relationship, etc.) as Rav Firstname. It does *not* seem to be considered as respectful as using Rav Lastname or simply "The Rav."

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky , I think I might know. How about the following world-reknown authorities: Reb Moshe (Feinstein), Rav Chaim (Kanievsky), and Rav Yaakov (Kamenetsky)?

Comment: @LN6595 In those instances, they each came from prominent rabbinic families. The use of the first name was to distinguish them from their widely known relatives, which is why their equally well known contemporaries (Rav Eliashiv, Kotler, and Ruderman) are all referred to by last name (or nickname). I have never heard of Rav Kanievsky referred to by his first name, only by his last and "The Steipler (Gaon)." Oh, wait, you were referring to his ***SON.*** My point stands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Halachically Speaking [here:](http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol3Issue27.pdf)

> One is permitted to refer to his father by name if one adds *uvi, abbah*, or *Rav*, etc. before the name. Some say one should add *uvi morei*. Similarly, one may say “I am the daughter of Mrs. so and so.”
>
> Many *poskim* say that this should not be done in the presence of the parent. Others say one is always forbidden to mention a parent’s name even with an added title. [In conclusion], Horav Moshe Feinstein zt”l (Igros Moshe Y.D. 1:133) permits adding a title when one needs to mention a parent’s name.
>
> (emphases original)

Rav Yaakov Kaminetzky in Emes L'Yaakov says as well that as long as you add a title or appellation it is permitted.

Seemingly, following the Halachic ruling of Rav Moshe Feinstein, in regards to the case presented the fact that the daughter is calling her mother "Morah" would mitigate the issues with using her first name.

***Note this site is not to be used in place of a Psak from a Rabbi***